# How to create a link with an image and a text?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to create a link with an image and text on it (HTML and CSS)? I'm able to do this, but I need something more:

When I hover my mouse over the image or the text I want...

1. ...to change the color of the text
2. ...to change the image

I did 1., but 2. doesn't work.

This is my code:

```css
.container{
    height: 700px;
    width: 350px;
    margin: 10%;
}
.container2{
    background-image: url('./image.jpg');
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
}
.container a:hover{
    color: red;
    background-image: url('./image2.jpg')
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <a href="#"><h1 class="container2">Some text</h1></a>
</div>
```

I'm a beginner at html and css, so any answer would be helpful. Thank you and sorry for my English (if I made a mistake).

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Please note, that it is expected that you have done sufficient research efford aswell as tried to solve an issue on your own!

Comment: if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: where are you actually struggeling? Add mroe focus to the question. I have still struggle to udnerstand what you want toa chieve and where you get stuck. You either can try to work with a background-image and use `:hover` selector or have to do scripting.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was trying to put here my code, but I can't find out how :-(. I'm struggeling with the hover part.

Comment: you have a button to add a code-snippet (Ctrl + M). On hover changes can be done in CSS by using the `:hover` selector. However they will not change HTML content just apply different CSS-rules. So you need to add the image and the text through CSS as explained in my answer

Comment: Thanks, I added my code and edited the question. I hope it's better now.

Comment: https://codepen.io/JJCrook/pen/eYWZNmm - Here is a working example I created for your original question

Answer (score 0):

To have a link you obviosly need an anchor (`<a></a>`).

1. To change an image source on hover would require JS. The workaround would be to not use the image tag to include an image within the anchor but to use a `background-image`. To have a `background-image` displayed within an anchor, we have to change it from being an inline-element to a block-level element: `a { display: block; }`. Then we can use the `:hover` selector and change the `background-image` there.

2-4. To add a text, change the text and the color of the text, we need to add a pseudo-element. We can use the `::after` pseudo-selector to create one. We use `a { position: relative; }` and `a::after { position: absolute; inset: 0; }` to have the `pseudo-element` that will include the text span the entire height and with of the anchor. Now we can use `color` to change the text-color and `content` to choose a text.

```css
a {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: url("https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0735.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

a::after {
  content: "not hovering";
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  color: red;
  font-size: 2em;
}

/* chanegs for hover */
a:hover {
  background-image: url("https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0736.jpg");
}

a:hover::after {
  content: "hovering";
  color: green;
}





/* for styling purpose only */
a::after,
a:hover::after {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
  display:flex
```

```html
<a href="#"></a>
```

Comment: One more question:  Your code changes the text. I don't want to change it, I want to add another text that will be another link. I don't know if it's possible to have a link on link. Is it?

Comment: No a Link within a Link is not valid